# eigenvector associated with largest eigenvalue in case of complex numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Matrix M:
$$
M = \left(\begin{array}{ccccc} 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 1\\ \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0\\ 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 1 & 0 \end{array}\right)
$$

Eigen Values of M:

x =

Diagonal Matrix

```
1.00000 + 0.00000i                    0                    0                    0                    0
                0  -0.02166 + 0.61359i                    0                    0                    0
                0                    0  -0.02166 - 0.61359i                    0                    0
                0                    0                    0  -0.47834 + 0.32060i                    0
                0                    0                    0                    0  -0.47834 - 0.32060i
```

Eigen Vectors of M:

v =

```
 0.65320 + 0.00000i   0.14493 - 0.44675i   0.14493 + 0.44675i   0.66235 + 0.00000i   0.66235 - 0.00000i
 0.32660 + 0.00000i  -0.36776 - 0.10512i  -0.36776 + 0.10512i  -0.47773 - 0.32019i  -0.47773 + 0.32019i
 0.48990 + 0.00000i  -0.44274 + 0.19720i  -0.44274 - 0.19720i  -0.28794 + 0.14170i  -0.28794 - 0.14170i
 0.24495 + 0.00000i   0.17321 + 0.35466i   0.17321 - 0.35466i   0.27619 + 0.03699i   0.27619 - 0.03699i
 0.40825 + 0.00000i   0.49236 + 0.00000i   0.49236 - 0.00000i  -0.17286 + 0.14150i  -0.17286 - 0.14150i
```

I am trying to get the eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue, but in case of complex numbers which eigenvalue is the largest. Is it possible to compare 2 complex numbers?
Comparing the norms of the complex numbers and deciding on the largest eigenvalue with the largest norm of the complex number seems plausible but what is the reasoning behind?

Comment: We can't tell you whether looking at the magnitude of the complex numbers makes sense unless you explain **why** you are looking for the largest eigenvalue in the first place.

Comment: Because you are looking at a column-stochastic matrix, it seems likely that you are concerned with the behavior of $M^k$ as $k \to \infty$. If this is the case, then yes: it makes sense to look for the eigenvalue with the largest magnitude. See also the [Perron Frobenius theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem).

Comment: Also, do you use matlab or python? If so, then it is easy to get output that is formatted according to the guidelines [explained here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/)

Comment: @BenGrossmann I am trying to sort pages according to pagerank algorithm and I need to calculate the largest eigenvalue to determine the corresponding eigenvector.

Comment: @BenGrossmann That is right, I am only concerned for large k as you mentioned but how do you correlate a column-stochastic matrix and M^{k} as k→∞. How do you make that interpretation?

Comment: @BenGrossmann I used octave/matlab. Thanks for your advice, I will take care of this output issue next time.

Comment: It would be ideal if you could take care of it this time. `latex(sym(M))` should do the trick; just paste the output between the delimiters `$$...$$`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is guaranteed by the [Perron Frobenius theroem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem), the largest eigenvalue (in magnitude) will necessarily by $1$, and this is the eigenvalue of interest.

Comment: Actually, there is something of a catch here: it is possible to have a stochastic matrix that is either periodic (which is accounted for in the PageRank algorithm with a damping factor) or disconnected (which means that the eigenvalue $1$ might correspond to multiple eigenvectors). For your particular matrix, neither of these occur.